# Kotlin - Way to get a substring starting from a specified index until another specified index or end of string?

Tags: string, kotlin, substring

Example

`val string = "Large mountain"`

I would like to get a substring starting from the index of the "t" character until index of "t" + 7 with the 7 being arbitrary or end of string.

`val substring = "tain"`

Assuming that the string is larger

`val string2 = "Large mountain and lake"`

I would like to return

`val substring2 = "tain and l"`

If my I were to try to substring(indexOf("t") ,(indexOf("t") + 7) )

In this second case right now if I use "Large mountain" I would get an index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Break down your problem into multiple steps. First get your initial substring, and then only limit to 10 characters if you need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's an especially elegant way to do this.

One fairly short and readable way is:

```
val substring = string.drop(string.indexOf('t')).take(7)
```

This uses [`indexOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/index-of.html) to locate the first `'t'` in the string, and then [`drop()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop.html) to drop all the previous characters, and [`take()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/take.html) to take (up to) 7 characters from there.

However, it creates a couple of temporary strings, and will give an IllegalArgumentException if there's no `'t'` in the string.

Improving robustness and efficiency takes more code, e.g.:

```
val substring = string.indexOf('t').let {
    if (it >= 0)
        string.substring(it, min(it + 7, string.length))
    else
        string
}
```

That version lets you control the result when there's no `'t'` (in the `else` branch); it also avoids creating any temporary objects. As before, it uses `indexOf()` to locate the first `'t'`, but then [`min()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/min.html) to work out how long the substring can be, and [`substring()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring.html) to generate it in one go.

If you were doing this a lot, you could of course put it into your own function, e.g.:

```
fun String.substringFrom(char: Char, maxLen: Int)
    = indexOf(char).let {
        if (it >= 0)
            substring(it, min(it + maxLen, length))
        else
            this
    }
```

which you could then call with e.g. `"Large mountain".substringFrom('t', 7)`